# Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. Conda Fails to Create a new env

Tags: anaconda, conda, anaconda3, conda-forge, mamba

** Conda Fails to Create a new env: stuck at "Executing transaction"**

I am working with a MacOS, BigSur 11.6, and have updated conda and mamba

`conda update --all`

`conda update mamba`

and, following guidance from a [software installation guide](https://github.com/fermi-lat/Fermitools-conda/wiki/Quickstart-Guide) I tried to create a new env:

`conda create -n fermi -c conda-forge -c fermi fermitools python=3 clhep=2.4.4.1`

Also tried with the dev version:

`conda create -n fermi-2.0.24 -c conda-forge -c fermi/label/dev fermitools=2.0.24`

and with mamba

`mamba create -n fermi -c conda-forge -c fermi fermitools python=3 clhep=2.4.4.1`

All trials get stuck in " executing transaction \ " (> 1h)

when hitting ctrl+c, all trials show the same error msg:

" ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::gdk-pixbuf-2.42.6-h2e6141f_0'. "
" Rolling back transaction: done "

my `uname -v:`

Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:21 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_X86_64

my `conda --version`

conda 4.10.3

There seems to be a long standing discussion about similar issues [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6986). Some argue that hitting "enter" solved the problem after " executing transaction \ " was running for a long time. It would be great, but did not worked.

The issue [#6986](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6986) seems to persist and it is not clear how to deal with it.

Any ideas on how to approach this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `conda create -n foo -c conda-forge gdk-pixbuf=2.42.6=h2e6141f_0` work on its own? BTW, I cannot replicate this problem in MacOS 10.14 - everything just works, both from bash and zsh shells.

Comment: Hi @merv, thank you for writing. Yes, ``conda create -n foo -c conda-forge gdk-pixbuf=2.42.6=h2e6141f_0`` worked. "To activate this environment, use conda activate foo" .

Comment: @merv, I tired to ``conda activate foo`` , and then ``conda create -n fermi-2.0.24 -c conda-forge -c fermi/label/dev fermitools=2.0.24`` , but the issue remains the same. And when I hit ctrl+c to stop the process, I get the same msg as before: " ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::gdk-pixbuf-2.42.6-h2e6141f_0'. " " Rolling back transaction: done "

Comment: But that's not any different from your original command, since you are doing **create**. Maybe try preinstalling the `gdk-pixbuf` package, then `conda install` in that environment.

Comment: Hi @merv, thank you again.  Now, I created the envs/fermi folder by hand: ``mkdir /opt/anaconda3/envs/fermi`` then, preinstall gdk-pixbuf-2.42.6-h2e6141f_0 pack (from conda-forge channel) at envs/fermi. ``conda install gdk-pixbuf=2.42.6=h2e6141f_0 -c conda-forge -n fermi`` .  Then, I used install instead of create (since env/fermi is already there). ``conda install -n fermi --file [path]/spec-file.txt``, where the spec-file has all dependences solved for MacOS BigSur 11.6 (provided by someone else trying to help with the issue).

Comment: This time, the process get stuck, and after ctrl+c, got the following msg:
 
Executing transaction: / \ / \ / done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::librsvg-2.50.7-hd2a7919_0'.
Rolling back transaction: | \ done . Again, I tried to pre-install librsvg=2.50.7=hd2a7919_0 as you mention, and try to run the complete installation again. A second time, it gets stuck, and I also had to pre-install graphviz-2.49.0=h77de9ca_0. A third time, it gets stuck at the same point. But now, when I abort with ctrl+c, there is no error msg.

Comment: when I ``conda activate myenv``, it goes with no error msg. But, when I try to call routines from myenv, I get 'zsh: command not found: env_routine'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking for resources on the error " Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. "

Then, reading:
[link1](https://exerror.com/solving-environment-failed-with-initial-frozen-solve-retrying-with-flexible-solve/)  ,  [link2](https://programmerah.com/solve-condas-solving-environment-failed-problem-4018/)  ,  [link3 (check the comment from "glass-ships")](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9004)  ,  [link4](https://dizzycoding.com/solving-environment-failed-with-repodata-from-current_repodata-json-will-retry-with-next-repodata-source-code-answer/)

It seems the following can help:

`conda update conda -c conda-canary`

`conda config --set channel_priority false`

`conda create --name your_env_name`

`conda activate your_env_name`

`conda install XXXXXX`

then `conda activate your_env_name` and the tool is working just fine.

Comment: not sure i had exactly the same issue, but for me the problem of conda stuck on solving environment when trying to create a new env was apparently due to the fact that i did not activate an environment before that. doing `conda activate` before `conda create` solved the issue for me (in my installation the base environment of conda is not activated by default).

Comment: This works great. I had the issue with conda stuck at solving environment for ages and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. Set the conda channel_priority to flexible in the conda configuration

```
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
```